# How to let users know special functionality of a component you created?

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, messages, tooltips

Lets say i create a grid view. The users are not technical and are higher ups so they dont have time to read documentation(or just lazy).

I have implemented copy and paste functionality in this grid via ctrl +v and ctrl +c

What is the best way that I can let them know they have the power to copy/paste via these commands without cluttering up  the grid with instruction text

Comment: Can you provide any other action to copy and paste grid besides ctrl +v/ ctrl +c ?

Comment: Yea they can also right click for a context menu and copy data but cannot paste via right click (web based so security)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a tooltip that appears when the mouse hovers over your grid that explains this functions exists. Adding a 'don't show this message again' button in the tooltip will allow users that already know about this function to stop it from triggering again as it can become annoying.

Something along the lines of:

Top Tip!
Did you know you can copy and paste (ctrl + c then ctrl + v) the data in this grid?

The hover feature allows you to save space on the interface while still providing information in the exact area it's applicable to.